# iOS: Best way to present and receive user input?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, user-behavior, ios, iphone

Background: I'm building an app that uses the camera to overlay objects (helmets, glasses, etc) over people's faces. I'm building a simple algorithm that checks if people are wearing glasses. Depending on the number of people wearing glasses, a custom hat is unlocked.

Requirement: Using this logic, I basically want to ask the user (in the settings section of the app) to specify the minimum amount of people that should wear glasses to trigger the custom hat. The lowest possible option is 1.

Problem / Dilemma: What's the best way of presenting this logic to the user, and collecting their input? I want it to be fun and very user-friendly, and realized that by using whole numbers (0,1,2,4), it would require the user to constantly go into the settings and change the number everytime they take pictures with a different number of people. Because of this I thought of using percentages or ratios, but I want the app to be as simple as possible (Don't want to scare anyone away with the math). I was thinking of using a Circular Slider that would allow the user to select anwhere from 25%-100%, and have their choice snap to either 25, 50, 75, or 100%. The problem with this is that I'm not sure circular sliders would be useful especially because in this case the user would only have 4 choices to select from, and anything lower than 25% isn't even a choice. What's a creative way of presenting this without using textfields, horizontal sliders, or buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I think you chose correctly by going for percentages instead of numbers.

Second, your asking for fun and innovative ways of selecting four different choices. The possibilities are endless and the only thing I can do is give you a link to [an article that I find inspiring](http://www.awwwards.com/creative-ui-design-examples-for-great-ux.html) and which has several circular elements that might inspire you too.

Comment: As obvious at it may seem (due to all the math) I honestly forgot what I wanted to do exactly, and you reminded me that it's all about selecting 4 different choices! Thank you for that. With that said I'll definitely take a look at that article!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing too much about your app, I would say that the idea of showing hats based on number of glasses could be too complex to explain to users in a quickly and fun way.

I would try to simply it:

- Maybe instead of asking for number of people with hats when the camera is on, you could just place that setting under "settings".
- Then place a toggle button "hats on!/no hats" during the picture taking process.

Comment: It's also a good idea to not let user to choose a number or percentage but rather give them more interesting variants like "all in glasses" and "some in glasses" and even "add hats randomly" (i.e. make it really like a game).

Comment: @alexeypegov that's interesting! I like that thank you, I'll definitely consider that approach.